# Laravel Global Storage

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables, laravel-5.1

I want to store result of a query in a session (or any global) variable, so that I can retrieve that variable from different controller or action in laravel 5.1. I'll take some time to explain it further, what's happening here is I am getting some data from the form, and after that I have to get some more data from a different page and perform a DB transaction only then.
    Earlier I used Zend Framework in which we had a storage object in which one could store data in almost any format. Here is my code snippet.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use App\Http\Requests; 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\curl\CurlRequestHandler;
use Config;
class MyController extends Controller
{
  public function myajax(Request $request)
{
    $data = "Some Data From DB operation";
  Session::put('myFormData', $data2);
       $value = Session::get('myFormData'); 
       print_r($value); //Works Fine
}
 public function someOtherFunction(Request $request){
       $val = Session::get('myFormData');
       print_r($val);die('check'); 
   // No data !
}
```

How do I get that data? I guess every time it hits a new action, session value is restored to default. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: If session restored itself to "default"  on every new action, it would be pretty useless.... the whole point of session is that it should be maintained between requests, not restored to default

Comment: Use Session namespace instead of Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session.

Answer (score 3):

Resolved the issue by using session instance via http request. $request->session()->put('test', $curlResponse); // inside myajax function. $value = $request->session()->get('test', 'default'); //in //someOtherFunction